# Are Israeli dual citizens allowed to cross via the Allenby Bridge?

Tags: borders, dual-nationality, jordan, palestine, israeli-citizens

The Allenby Bridge is located on the border between Jordan and the West Bank. Wiki [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allenby_Bridge#The_Allenby_border_crossing) the following restrictions for Israelis:

> Israeli citizens are not permitted to use the terminal, except pilgrims to Mecca, the Hajj and Omra.

Does this provision also apply to dual citizens of Israel? E.g. someone who is also a citizen of Russia?

Comment: Are Israeli citizens formally allowed to travel into or out of Israel using foreign passports?

Comment: @phoog I don't think so. I am not a dual citizen, but I have literally seen dual citizens trying to leave Israel on a USA passport taken away by police.

Comment: @phoog definitely not, but if the restriction is imposed by Jordan - they might allow double citizens in through that bridge.

Comment: I do not know how the bridge is arranged but if it's anything like the crossing at Eilat then you present your paperwork separately to Israeli and Jordanian authorities and maybe you could present a separate passport to each

Comment: @chx according to the Israeli Airport Authority, which operates the terminal despite its not being an airport, Israeli citizens may use the terminal only with a Jordanian entrance visa.  See http://www.iaa.gov.il/Rashat/en-US/Borders/Alenbi/AbouttheTerminal/TheHistoryoftheTerminal/.  It would therefore not be possible to present different passports to the Israeli and Jordanian authorities, and it appears that the decision whether to allow an Israeli to use the crossing rests with Jordan.

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work :( but that visa requirement is not only for Israeli citizens. http://international.visitjordan.com/generalinformation/gettingaround/bordercrossings.aspx says:  You can also obtain a visa upon arrival at Amman’s Queen Alia International Airport or at any other border crossing (except the King Hussein Bridge (Allenby Bridge) and the ferryboat from Egypt). So that's a Jordanian requirement. I wonder whether Israel authorities would let you pass if you showed them you are a dual citizen AND have a visa?

Comment: @chx It's possible that the Wiki is wrong and all you need is a pre-arranged visa

Comment: @JonathanReez so you're attempting to conceal your nationality and enter a country illegally?

Comment: @hownowbrowncow There are many-many situations where double citizens are treated differently, without breaking any laws. E.g. a citizen of Russia can't enter the Schengen area without a visa, but can freely do so on his Israeli passport.

Comment: @JonathanReez you and I both know it is doubtful that this is one of those cases here Jonathan.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow If you find a good source, feel free to post "No, it's impossible"

Comment: @chx the page I linked to has a section called "Departing Travelers" which reads in part "Israeli citizens are required to present an entry visa to Jordan."

Comment: @JonathanReez it is one thing for a country to treat dual citizens of other countries differently: A Russian citizen who is also an Israeli citizen can choose to be treated by the Schengen area as an Israeli.  But it's much odder to think that a country would treat its *own* citizens more favorably if they hold another citizenship: Israel will generally treat its citizens as Israelis no matter what other citizenships they may hold.  Both situations follow from the same principle and the first doesn't imply that one should expect differential treatment in the second.

Comment: @phoog It's possible that Jordan bans Israeli travelers, but allows Israelis to be treated as a citizen of a different country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website of the United States Department of State suggests that this is not possible:

> Individuals with Israeli citizenship, **regardless of other nationality**, including U.S. citizenship, are prohibited from entering Gaza, **entering or departing Jordan via the Allenby/King Hussein Bridge**, and are generally prohibited from traveling to parts of the West Bank under PA control (Area A), to include Bethlehem and Jericho.

A later section of the same page elaborates a little:

> **Travel to and from Jordan**: Israeli citizens, including dual U.S.-Israeli citizens, are prohibited from using the Allenby/King Hussein Bridge crossing, unless as part of an official delegation or with special permission from the Israeli and Jordanian authorities. They must cross at the Yitzhak Rabin/Wadi Araba crossing in the south, near Eilat or the Jordan River crossing/Sheikh Hussein Bridge in the north, near Beit She’an.

Source: [travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/israel.html) information page on travel to Israel.

The website of the Israeli Airports Authority (which manages the Allenby crossing) appears to corroborate this:

> **The Allenby Border Terminal is reserved for Palestinians and tourists only; Israeli citizens are prohibited from crossing the border here.** Indeed, the terminal is used mainly by the Palestinian population from the West Bank, and throughout the years it has operated in tight cooperation between Israel, the Palestinian Authority and Jordan.

Source: [Israeli Airports Authority > Land Borders > Allenby > About](http://www.iaa.gov.il/en-US/borders/alenbi/Pages/About.aspx)

Comment: This possibly contradicts the official Allenby bridge website. An Israeli or Jordanian source would be far more reliable, as borders in the Middle East have a tendency to change rules very fast.

Comment: @JonathanReez Updated with information from IAA website.

Answer (score 4):

The official Israeli website of the [Allenby border crossing](http://www.iaa.gov.il/en-US/borders/Alenbi/Pages/default.aspx) mentions the following:

> Crossing the border at the terminal requires a valid passport with an expiration date at least six months after the departure date and all required documents for exiting:
>
> Entry visa to Jordan clearly stating that the crossing is through the Allenby Border Terminal.
>
> ...
>
> Israeli citizens are required to present an entry visa to Jordan.

Therefore I presume that the only restriction is that Jordanian visas-on-arrival are not issued at the Allenby border crossing for Israelis. However it is evidently possible for them to use the bridge.

In addition, according to a [Jordanian government website](http://www.dos.gov.jo/4th/Guiding_info.html):

> Single and multiple entry visas are available in advance from Jordanian embassies and consulates abroad. Single entry visas are also issued to EU, USA, Canadian, Australian, and New Zealand nationals at all land, sea and air borders **except the King Hussein (Allenby) Bridge**.

So the restriction seems to apply to citizens of all visa-on-arrival countries, not just Israel.

Comment: Off-topic, but could you please tell me what email address you contacted them on? I have a question for them as well but it's not easy to find the right address

Comment: @Crazydre I've used their web-form: https://www.iaa.gov.il/en-us/rashot/Pages/Contact-us.aspx